# google places api get location's reference value

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I have this string of code from one of their examples that I'm trying to reverse engineer.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(36.018486,-86.787607),
      zoom: 15
    });
    var frontline = new google.maps.LatLng(36.018486,-86.787607);

    var request = {
      reference: 'CnRkAAAAGnBVNFDeQoOQHzgdOpOqJNV7K9-c5IQrWFUYD9TNhUmz5-aHhfqyKH0zmAcUlkqVCrpaKcV8ZjGQKzB6GXxtzUYcP-muHafGsmW-1CwjTPBCmK43AZpAwW0FRtQDQADj3H2bzwwHVIXlQAiccm7r4xIQmjt_Oqm2FejWpBxLWs3L_RoUbharABi5FMnKnzmRL2TGju6UA4k'
    };

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

    service.getDetails(request, function(place, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: place.geometry.location
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
          infowindow.setContent(place.name);
          infowindow.open(map, this);
        });
      }
    });
  }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

I can't figure out how to find the reference for my location.

Also, how would I get multiple values into

```
infowindow.setContent()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that if you use the `textSearch()` method, that it provides the illusive reference string.  I wrote a client side script that uses the `textSearch()` method to provide the reference string for the `getDetails()` method [here](http://www.truelightdesigns.com/googleplacesreference.html).

Answer (score 1):

The long encrypted string is the Place reference, but it should only be used to go back and find the same place. Since it can change slightly it shouldn't be used to group ratings, check-ins, or other activity.

From the Places API documentation:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/

> "reference contains a unique token that you can use to retrieve
>   additional information about this place in a Place Details request.
>   You can store this token and use it at any time in future to refresh
>   cached data about this Place, but the same token is not guaranteed to
>   be returned for any given Place across different searches."

To add multiple values into the infowindow you just add what details you want show. Like this:

> infowindow.setContent(place.name + address + rating);

Comment: So I have it set up now to do a search for the business and return a reference value.  Problem is I can get info like the rating and name with place.rating and place.name, but cannot get stuff like  the formatted_address and geometry even if I try it place.formatted_address or results [0].formatted_address.

Comment: Can you post a link to your page that replicates this? I used the reference above, and it works fine - formatted_address and geometry are populated.

Answer (score 0):

var request
Is where there are setting their data for the locations.  Looks to be fairly encrypted.

Comment: I know.  There isn't much mention of it in the api other than where you need put it, but it is what tells what the actual place is.